# Why the output of my programme is 495 instead of 496

Tags: c++

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
class obj
{
    int arr[100],i,nod,sum;
    public:
    int init()
    {
        arr[0] = 4;
        arr[1] = 9;
        arr[2] = 6;
        nod = 3;
        sum = 0;
        sum = parseInt(arr);
        return sum;
    }
    int parseInt(int arr[])
    {
        for(i=nod-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            sum = sum + arr[i] * pow(10,nod-1-i);
        }
        return sum;
    }
};
int main()
{
    obj o;
    cout<<o.init();
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: You should get a debugger and step through it. That would be faster than asking someone else to do the same.

Comment: Your code runs good and outputs 496: https://ideone.com/t4DEJm

Answer (score 0):

The function `std::pow` is floating point (double), the rounding to int is truncating. Once any result is inexact (e.g. 99.999999999 instead of 100) it will be truncated and you will get a lower value than expected.